# Adding Form Input Values to InnerHTML Output

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to code a form that creates a custom sentence based on the inputs a user selects. For example, my form has one written inputs and two dropdowns. I want this data added to my innerHTML. Say I wanted to create a custom sentence about a dog the layout would look like this:

> My dog's name is (value from input 1). (Value from dropdown 1) loves
>   to play fetch. My dog is (value from dropdown 2).

```js
function sentence() {
  document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "My dog's name is (value from input 1). (Value from dropdown 1) loves to play fetch. My dog is (value from dropdown 2).";
}
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.display {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="text" placeholder="Your Dog's Name" name="name" maxlength="100"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="gender">
        <option value="He">He</option>
        <option value="She">She</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="size">
        <option value="Big">Big</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Small">Small</option>
      </select>
    </td>
</table>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<p id="s1">

</p>
<br>

<div class="display">
  <button onclick="sentence()"> Button </button>
</div>

<p id="s1">

</p>
```

Comment: You can get the relevant data using `document.getElementById('theid').value`. All you need to do is change `name` to `id`  (`name` is for forms that get sent to the server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do the trick!

```
function sentence()
{
  const v1 = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value,
        v2 = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value,
        v3 = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1].value
  document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML="My dog's name is " + v1 + ". " + v2 + "loves to play fetch. My dog is " + v3 + ".";
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks a million.

Comment: @PhilMotto if it's the answer vote it up or select it as the answer <3 (that's how this site works.) and welcome to the community!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :)

```js
function sentence() {
 var nameDog = document.getElementById( "name" ),
  
  genderDog = document.getElementById( "gender" ),
  
  sizeDog = document.getElementById( "size" ),
  
  result = document.getElementById( "s1" );
 
 if ( nameDog.value == "" ) {
  
  result.innerHTML = "Write name your dog's";
  
 } else {
  
  result.innerHTML = "My dog's name is " + nameDog.value + ", " + genderDog.value + " loves to play fetch. My dog is " + sizeDog.value;
  
 }
};
```

```css
table, td, th {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto
}

.display {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input id="name" placeholder="Your Dog's Name" type="text">
  </td>

  <td><select id="gender">
   <option value="he">
    he
   </option>

   <option value="she">
    she
   </option>
  </select>
  </td>

  <td><select id="size">
   <option value="big">
    big
   </option>

   <option value="medium">
    medium
   </option>

   <option value="small">
    small
   </option>
  </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br>

<hr>
<br>


<div class="display">
 <button onclick="sentence()">Button</button>
</div>


<p id="s1">
</p>
```